# Webview is not redirecting to the webpage from gmail login

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using webview to open any customer review sites like TripAdvisor or zomato where users can login and give review but the problem i am facing is after login through gmail from the review sites example TripAdviser ,the webview is just showing blank page, its not redirecting to the TripAdviser page. does webview is restricted? Please guid me through the right direction.

**My Code:**

```
var myweb = new WebView (){
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
Source = "https://www.tripadvisor.in/Register",
};
```

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati Stop adding "thanks" to questions. We are supposed to *remove* the fluff, not add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the request like

```
myweb.LoadRequest(NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(new NSUrl("https://www.tripadvisor.in/Register" )))
```